# Highlight text from SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I would like to highlight a specific part of text which is coming from SQL query. The string which should be replaced is coming from the following code:

```
$highlight = $_GET['highlight'];
```

I then have the query which is showing the actual text, here is some part of this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<?php echo $row['text']; ?>
```

What I want to do is if in this text the text from the string `$highlight` exists to be highlighted. I tried putting a function with pregreplace before the query is executed but that didn't work.

```
<?php 

function highlight($text_highlight, $highlight) {
  $str = preg_replace('#'. preg_quote($text_highlight) .'#i', '<span style="background-color:#FFFF66; color:#FF0000;">\\0</span>', $highlight);
  return $str;
}

?>
```

Comment: What's the output of your current code?

Comment: The outut is text from the database from column called text. from which text I would like strings to be highlighted which are equals to the $highlight

Comment: I mean, what does the current code do? You only told us you "don't have any luck" without being more specific.

Comment: The current code is displaying the text from the query, but it is not replacing anything. the same text which is equal to the text inside $highlight is no getting changed

Comment: Actually, the code seems to work fine for me. Are you sure you're calling the functions in the right parameter order (the parameter names aren't very good IMO)? What's the value of `$highlight`?

Comment: $highligh=LA%20SEGUNDA%20SALA%20DEL%20TRIBUNAL

Comment: And you're sure this string appears in the text from your database? It seems to me you should have a look at `urldecode()`.

Comment: Probably I am missing something in the part when the array 'text' is being rendered , so the function will be called and actualy the text will be replaced. regarding the string if it is apering inside the text from the database yes. I tried ever with one word, no change

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed with easier solution

```
<?php echo str_ireplace($highlight, '<span style="color: #000000;
background-color:#FFFF66;">'.$highlight.'</span>', $row['text']); ?>
<?php
```